# C# Can't read nested nodes from SOAP Service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm calling a SOAP service which is returning an XML response which I capture as a type specified in the service contract. The response is displaying certain nested nodes as null, even though when I view the raw response in Fiddler, the nodes contain data. Looking at the Reference.cs class generated by the service, all nodes have the proper XML namespace specified. I thought maybe it had to do with the basicHttpBinding but that's just a guess. Below is my binding, the values are high just until I get it working.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "ServiceSoapBinding";
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.AllowCookies = true;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 20000000;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 20000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 20000000;
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://serviceURL");
var client = new ServiceClient(binding, address);
```

Below is the class that the response sees as null even though I know the service is returning data:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://NamespaceURL")]
public partial class CustomerType: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{...}
```

Any ideas?